# Wait for token retrieval before http

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a service for fetching data that will first make sure there is a valid token.

My code is this:

**AccountService:**

```
export class AccountService {

    private tokenUrl = 'api/account/authorize';  
    private _token: Token;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient) { }

    /** GET token information from the server */
    getToken(refresh: boolean): Observable<Token> {
        if (!!this._token && !refresh) {
            console.log('returning cached token', this._token);
            return of(this._token);
        }
        return new Observable(observer =>{
            this.http.post<Token>(this.tokenUrl, {})
            .pipe(
                tap(token => this._token = token),
                tap(token => observer.next(token)),
                catchError(this.handleError('getToken', null))
            );
        })
    }
}
```

I am also trying to cache the token received so i do not have to do the post every time the token is requested, unless it is explicitely requested.

**InfoService:**

```
@Injectable()
export class InfoService {

    private infoBaseUrl = 'api/info/';  // URL to web api
    private _selectionOptions: SelectionOptionsResult;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private accountService: AccountService) { }

    getfilterOptions(filters: SelectionOptionRequest): Observable<SelectionOptionsResult> {

        var tokenObservable = this.accountService.getToken(false);

        console.log('THIS SUCCESFULLY HITS');

        return tokenObservable.switchMap((token) => {

            console.log('THIS NEVER HITS');

            let httpParams = new HttpParams();
            Object.keys(filters).forEach(function (key) {
                httpParams = httpParams.append(key, filters[key]);
            });
            var httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.access_Token
                }),
                params: httpParams
            };  

            return this.http.get<SelectionOptionsResult>(this.infoBaseUrl + 'GetfilterOptions', httpOptions)
                .pipe(
                    tap(so => this._selectionOptions = so),
                    catchError(this.handleError('getfilterOptions', null))
                );

        })
    }
}
```

**component**

```
getfilterOptions(filters: SelectionOptionRequest): void {
    this.infoService.getfilterOptions(filters)
        .subscribe(so => this.filterOptions = so);
}
```

Though it does go into `getFilterOptions`, it never reaches the `getToken`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses "cold" observables (https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339). Therefore it will never be executed up until you subscribe to it. I believe if you'll slightly change your code to

```
var tokenObservable = this.accountService.getToken(false).subscribe(() => {});
```

Everything will start to work as expected. I'm like 99% sure in that , so let me know if it will not fix your code.

Comment: @Giannis, What's mean "!!this._token", I think that the correct is if (!this.token) -only one !-

Comment: @Eliseo !this.token means null or undefined. !!this.token means not null or undefined. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @Vitalii I will have to read through this link you sent. At the moment i tried your suggestion, but since subscribe returns a Subscription instead of an Observable, i am not able to use the switchMap afterwards.

Comment: See below, maybe you can `.pipe()` those calls then

Answer (score 0):

sorry ::glups::
Why not? (I don't know the function of observer.next(token))

```
return this.http.post<Token>(this.tokenUrl, {})
            .pipe(
                tap(token => this._token = token),
                catchError(this.handleError('getToken', null))
            );
        })
```

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to what i already have? What i am trying to accomplish is to fist make sure i have the token before trying to request any other resource from the server.